# qt webkit 5.x instability - crashing - your experience?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I am looking for some advice on a qt-web kit issue.
I have already raised this issue on the qt web forum but I have received no response yet.
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/50059/

I constantly seeing crashes in QtWebKit.
For example, the example FancyBrowser. 
Version 5.3.1 - 5.3.2 and 5.4
It appears to me after a huge amount of testing that there is heap corruption in 
QtWebKit but I am surprised it is not more reported as it happens fairly easily and if you 
enable full page heap checking on windows it happens all the time.

Has anyone any experience with this issue! Do you find webkit stable? have you tried the fancy browser example?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using qt libs as static library or dlls ?

Comment: I am using the dlls. I spent time searching https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa most of the issues I had are reported under fancy browser, I guess the next release will be better:)